# HDD hard drive went from 500 gigs to 1 gigs after powerout during dd operation

Tags: hard-drive, drive, dd

i had a HDD 500 gigs hard drive ticking, i attempted to fix it using the line `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=4M` so t detects the ticking sectors and removes them from the future writings(it actually stopped ticking).
after reaching about 265 gigs of writing the zeros successfully the power supply shutdown and dd process halted
When i attempted to continue from the last address given using `seek=16443` option it says:

```
 sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=4M seek=16443 status=progress
 [sudo] password for mohamed: 
 dd: error writing '/dev/sdb': No space left on device
 1+0 records in
 0+0 records out
 0 bytes copied, 0.0150227 s, 0.0 kB/s
```

i tried to open gparted but it shows the follwoing message

```
 No space left on device during write on /dev/sdb

 /dev/sdb: unrecognised disk label
```

trying to use `sudo smartctl -i /dev/sdb` to get the data about the device yields the following

```
Smartctl open device: sdb [USB JMicron] failed: Invalid argument
```

gparted currently shows the space as 63.1G unallocated , whenever i try to make a new partition table it says there is no space left
even when i `#ls` in `/dev/` folder all the drivers are in bold yellow except sdb shows as normal white thin font
here is the output of `lsblk`

```
NAME           MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sdb              8:16   0 465.8G  0 disk  
sr0             11:0    1  1024M  0 rom   
sda              8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk  
├─sda2           8:2    0 244.1G  0 part  
├─sda7           8:7    0   5.9G  0 part  
│ └─cryptswap1 253:0    0   5.9G  0 crypt [SWAP]
├─sda5           8:5    0   200G  0 part  
├─sda1           8:1    0 186.5G  0 part  
├─sda8           8:8    0  38.2G  0 part  /
└─sda6           8:6    0 256.4G  0 part
```

I hope to gain help
thanks

Comment: A "ticking" HDD strongly suggests a mechanical problem. Looks like it's dead. That's life, HDDs don't last forever.

Comment: it is actually running normally now without any ticking, just undetected for anything else

Comment: how to make sure that it is dead not that the power thing messed it up?

Comment: The power thing may have messed it up indeed. The final punch, so to speak. There isn't very much you can do if there is a mechanical/electric problem.

Comment: What happens if you start dd from the beginning?

Comment: When i start dd from the begining it writes 1.9 gigs of data then says that it is now full